# LWC querySelectorAll is not working

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, salesforce1-app, lwc-dom

I am trying to iterate Student name as a `button` on click of button i need to show the students details below.

For this, by default i kept the button class as `slds-button_neutral` on click of any of the student i need to change the button type to `slds-button_brand`

**For Example:**
Iteration of the student

Student 1           Student 2           Student 3

All student button  slds style will be  will be `slds-button_neutral`.

If i click the Student 2, button  slds style will be changed as `slds-button_brand` for Student 2. Student 1 and 3 will remains the same style. End user want's to know which student i selected.

To achieve this i wrote the below code, I don't see any error, But It's not working, Can any one help what is that  I am missing here.

**HTML**

```
 <template for:each={contactSearchList} for:item="family" for:index="index">
             
            <div key={family.id}
                class="slds-p-around_none slds-m-top_x-small slds-m-bottom_medium slds-m-horizontal_none">
                <lightning-layout>
                    <template for:each={family.student} for:item="student" for:index="index">
                        <lightning-layout-item key={student.id} flexibility="auto" padding="around-small">
                            <div class="  slds-p-around_medium slds-text-align_center">
                                <button class="slds-button slds-button_neutral studentButton" name="studentInfo_btn"
                                    data-isactive="false" onclick={handleselectStudent}>{student.lastName}
                                    <span class="slds-p-right_x-small"></span>
                                    {student.firstName}</button></div>
                        </lightning-layout-item>

                    </template>
                </lightning-layout>
            </div>

        </template>
```

**JS**

```
 handleselectStudent(event) {
const studentInfobtns = this.template.querySelectorAll(
      "button.slds-button slds-button_neutral studentButton"
    );
    alert(studentInfobtns + "" + studentInfobtns.length);
    if (
      studentInfobtns.length !== undefined &&
      studentInfobtns.length != null
    ) {
      alert("first if");
      studentInfobtns.forEach((studentInfobtn) => {
        studentInfobtn.className = "slds-button slds-button_brand";
      });
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try ? `this.template.querySelectorAll("button.slds-button.slds-button_neutral.studentButton");`

Answer (score 1):

It is not recommended to manipulate the DOMs using Javascript, because the LWC run time does it in a very efficient manner. If you use the javascript properties, you can achieve this like below.

Pass in the unique `id` of the student and family as data attributes to the button like below.
You also need a property on each student record to set the class dynamically.

```
<div key={family.id} class="slds-p-around_none slds-m-top_x-small slds-m-bottom_medium slds-m-horizontal_none">
    <lightning-layout>
        <template for:each={family.student} for:item="student" for:index="index">
            <lightning-layout-item key={student.id} flexibility="auto" padding="around-small">
                <div class="  slds-p-around_medium slds-text-align_center">
                    <button data-student-id={student.id} data-family-id={family.id} class={student.buttonClass} name="studentInfo_btn"
                        data-isactive="false" onclick={handleselectStudent}>{student.lastName}
                        <span class="slds-p-right_x-small"></span>
                        {student.firstName}</button></div>
            </lightning-layout-item>

        </template>
    </lightning-layout>
</div>
```

> **Note:** If you are using the standard `Id` field, the `I` is capital in it like `Id` and not 'id' which you have in the code, so consider changing if needed.

Then in the handler based on the button, you can manipulate the js property.

```
// make sure the list contactSearchList is annotated with the @track attribute.
handleselectStudent(event){
     let familyId = this.contactSearchList.findIndex(event.dataset.familyId);
     this.contactSearchList[familyId].forEach( student => {
         if(student.id === event.target.dataset.studentId){
              student.buttonClass = 'slds-button slds-button_brand studentButton';
         } else {
             student.buttonClass = 'slds-button slds-button_neutral studentButton';
         }
     })
}
```

Everytime you load the data, you will need to set the default class to `slds-button slds-button_neutral studentButton` in wire/imperative apex.